# Python process a cmd command which opens another tool

Tags: python, cmd

I have a problem when sending a cmd command in python. This command opens another tool, giving it some arguments. The problem is that the tool is opening, but also opens a cmd window, where I can see the message sent. If I close this cmd window, the tool will be closed, like a child process. This is odd: I just want to open the tool, without any cmd window being opened.

If I do it manually, by creating a .bat file which I double click, it works normally (a cmd is opened for 0.1 seconds while the tool is opening, without any cmd file still attached to the tool).

Big picture: I've created a tool which will ask for some paths and then you can click "start tool", those paths are send as arguments to the tool which will be opened.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: you want it for windows or linux

Comment: I want it for windows 10. I am opening the interface using a bat file, which contains: C:\Users\Vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe -i DebugerSetup.py. This will bring to life the interface behind the .py file, but as i said, the cmd will stays behind the UI, and if i close the cmd, the application window (UI) will close also. I want that after double click on the .bat file, which opens the .py interface, to open properly the application and then close the opened cmd, without closing the app also.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no problem** with the **CMD window** since whatever script you're writing is opening the **applications** which you're passing in arguments but **through the CMD window** only.

And you talked about a **batch file** that too works via **CMD window** only. Please check the flow of your code and also note or find out how it works at the back end. Is it taking the help of CMD Window?

Comment: i want to open the .py file, which has an design, so i want to open the app which is in the .py file from a bat file (python.exe -i DebuggerSetup.py). This will bring on a cmd which will stays on while the app is on. I want just the app to stay, and the cmd to disappear.

Comment: You can't -- executing a batch file with the built-in Command Prompt is going to keep a window open until the batch file exits.

Comment: What you can do is take steps to make sure that the batch file exits as quickly as possible. If at all possible, modify the batch file to run whatever program with the start command. By default, start returns immediately without waiting for the program to exit, so the batch file will continue to run and, presumably, exit immediately. Couple that with modifying your shortcut to run the batch file minimized, and you'll only see the taskbar flash without even seeing a window onscreen.

Comment: A final possibility is to use a 3rd-party tool to run the command prompt with a hidden window. I've heard of such things but never had a use for them, so I don't know of anything, in particular, to point you to.

Comment: One caveat to this is that if you're running a console-mode program, which many script interpreters are, the batch file will wait for the program to exit, and using start will spawn a new console window. What you need to do in this case is run the Windows-based version of the interpreter instead of the console-based one -- no start necessary. For Perl, you would run wperl.exe instead of perl.exe. For Python, it's pythonw.exe instead of python.exe. The old win32 Ruby distribution I have downloaded has rubyw.exe, which should do the same thing.

Comment: I will repeat. When i am trying to open a .py file, which contains and user interface (an aplication with an interface), it will come with a cmd file, which keeps the interface alive.. i don't want that.

Comment: If i enter idle for example, and i click run to the .py file, there is no cmd opened, just the interface..